# Starting slash in FW/1 route pattern matching

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

I am reviewing the configuration of FW/1. I notice that some of the routes start with a `/` and others don't. Is there any difference between the two?

```
variables.framework.routes = [
   { "chart/home"                           = "chart/home"},
   ...
   { "/location/home"                       = "location/home"},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you noticed any difference in behavior from the two?  I don't think there is a difference. From the documentation and examples that I could find they are all preceded by a `/`. I presume that FW/1 is allowing both but they work the same.

Snippet from the documentation here - http://framework-one.github.io/documentation/developing-applications.html#url-routes:

> URL Routes
>
> In addition to the standard `/section/item` and `/module:section/item` URLs that FW/1 supports ...

An example from farther down that page shows the standard routes starting with a `/`:

> Here’s an example showing all the features together:
>
> ```
> variables.framework.routes = [
> { "/product/:id" = "/product/view/id/:id", "/user/{id:[0-9]+}" = "/user/view/id/:id",
>   hint = "Display a specific product or user" },
> { "/products" = "/product/list", "/users" = "/user/list" },
> { "/old/url" = "302:/new/url" }
> ```
>
> ];

Here is a link to the code that processes the routes you define - https://github.com/framework-one/fw1/blob/develop/framework/one.cfc#L1954-L2047

In order to test this theory you could try the following.

- Browse to `www.yourdomain.com/location/home` that should match the second route in your example.
- Browse to `www.yourdomain.com/chart/home` that should match the first route in your example.
- Browse to `www.yourdomain.com/sometextchart/home` does that match the first route in your example?
- Browse to `www.yourdomain.com/somefolder/chart/home` does that match the first route in your example?
- Browse to `www.yourdomain.com/somefolder/sometextchart/home` does that match the first route in your example?